# Do Form POST in Google Apps Script with HtmlService?

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, web-applications

I'm trying to do a wizard type application with Google Apps Script. Since styling with UiApp is so pain in the rear, I'm trying with the HtmlService route. I can't get the form POST working. Here's my sample code:

```
// Code.gs
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('p1');
}

function doPost(e) {
  var params = Utilities.jsonStringify(e);
  var page = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('p2');
  page.params = params;
  return page.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```

p1.html

```
<div>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="myContents"></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
  </form>
</div>
```

p2.html

```
<div>
  <?=params?>
</div>
```

The output I've gotten from clicking "Submit" on p1 is

> {"queryString":null,"parameter":{},"contextPath":"","parameters":{},"contentLength":0}

I'm expecting the form to return data to me so that I can use the data in the consequent page. I'm wondering if this had anything to do with Caja poisoning. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting itself doesn't work in HtmlService due to security restrictions imposed by [Google Caja.](https://developers.google.com/caja/)

The correct way to do "form posts" in HtmlService is using `google.script.run` syntax to call server side functions with client side context. See here for a detailed example - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html-service-communication#forms

Comment: As I expected Caja is the poison. However, this makes very little sense because I have no way of serving the next page. Is there a way to trigger it?

Comment: No way to trigger it, unfortunately. If you go with an AJAX type approach, then you can update the UI without serving up a new page. See an example here of a new Task getting added and updating the UI using jQuery - https://github.com/google/google-apps-script-samples/tree/master/simple_tasks

Comment: Okay, I found a plan B. I can still replace href within an <a> element, so I can play CSS tricks to style the <a> to look like a button ... Thanks for the answer anyway.