# doPost stopped working google app script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have had an HTML Service script that has worked for at least 8 months that uses a doGet for the first page and doPost of all subsequent pages.

Yesterday, when I loaded the page, the doGet works fine, pulls info from a spreadsheet and renders the the form. Regardless of what selections I make, the submit button does nothing.

I then went back to my personal gmail account, unrelated to the production account, untouched and using private dummy copies of data, where I originally coded it and that one no longer works.

I looked in the execution transcripts and it shows proper html rendering to the bottom of the first page, but nothing else.

Has doPost been retired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a working script fail recently, the fix was to force the Sandbox emulation mode to EMULATED.

The default mode WAS emulated with a caveat in the docs saying this could change.

Without seeing your code I'm not sure if that is relevant or not....

```
function doGet() {
  var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("FormHtml");
  html = html.evaluate();
  html.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.EMULATED);
  return html;
}
```

Comment: worked for me too but only if doGet is SandboxMode.IFRAME and doPost is SandboxMode.EMULATED .... anyone know why ?

Comment: but doesn't work on do Post a 2nd time with the exact same form NB see here if trying to use non-ajax forms (it appears to not be supported at all!) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585593/do-form-post-in-google-apps-script-with-htmlservice