# Is google apps script HTML service still supported?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been trying to make some basic web apps using google apps script, but I can't get the doPost to function.  When I looked for examples, everything was 2 years old, and all the example scripts no longer ran properly.  Is google apps script dead, or just unpopular?

Comment: FYI see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18585593/do-form-post-in-google-apps-script-with-htmlservice

Answer (score 1):

[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) and its [HTMLService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) are very much alive and well. It is well maintained and constantly enhanced by Google, with new APIs/Services added. Not sure what examples you were looking at - you did not specify that in your question, - but all examples of GAS code on Google Apps Script Developers site linked above work fine.

If you have specific questions about doPost() method (or any other GAS services/classes/methods/etc) - please do ask, following recommendations in [How yo ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to include the actual code you're working with in your question wrapped in code tags, but the minimum for [HtmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) is

```
function doGet() { 
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("hello world"); 
}
```

Publish > Deploy as web app > Save a version > Deploy

You get 2 URLs from that. A production one in text box and a development one in the latest code link.

RIP Google Apps Script?